# Maven overrides transitive dependency

Tags: java, maven

Overall applicatiom I'm using `Apache HttpComponents` dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But also another library uses this artifact, but different version (4.3.2, not 4.5.2):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is that API between this versions is changed and I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts
```

How I can say to maven not to override Sendgrid's version of HttpComponents (4.3.2) with 4.5.2?

EDIT: version of `httpcomponents` is specified in `dependencyManagement` section of parent pom

Comment: you try exclude the maven dependency?

Comment: @soorapadman I want allow Sendgrid to use it's own version of `httpcomponents`, but maven overrides by newer version of `httpcomponents` which I'm using in other places

Comment: you can re-declare the transitive dependency with the version you want, you can do it in the `dependencyManagement` section for clarity.

Comment: @A.DiMatteo `pom.xml` where I declared `sendgrid`, already has definition of `httpcomponents`. How I can redeclare it?

Comment: which version of sendgrid-java are using? 2.2?

Comment: This is likely going to be a problem.  A class loader can only load a single version of a library.  Most applications will have a single classpath which loads a collection of jars.  This classpath can only have one version of httpcomponents.  In this case, you will have to downgrade your entire application to use 4.3.2.  There are alternative solutions which involve using multiple class loaders (e.g. OSGI bundles I think do this) but it will affect the entire loading of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following parent `pom.xml` section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<modules>
    <module>module-a</module>
    <module>module-b</module>
</modules>
```

Indeed in module-a the dependency tree is the following, executing:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

We get as part of the output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ module-a ---   
[INFO] com.sample:module-a:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   
[INFO] \- com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:jar:2.0.0:compile   
[INFO]    +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile   
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile   
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile     
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile   
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile   
[INFO]    +- com.sendgrid:smtpapi-java:jar:1.0.0:compile   
[INFO]    \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.4:compile
```

Note:

- We get `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile`
- We also get `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile`
- A potential versons mismatch happens here between libraries of the same family

Adding then to the module-a's `pom.xml` the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And re-running our dependency tree execution, we get as part of the output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ module-a ---  
[INFO] com.sample:module-a:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  
[INFO] \- com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:jar:2.0.0:compile   
[INFO]    +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile  
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile  
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2:compile  
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile  
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile  
[INFO]    +- com.sendgrid:smtpapi-java:jar:1.0.0:compile  
[INFO]    \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.4:compile
```

We now get `httpcore` and `httpclient` aligned, with the versions we wanted.

Also note the `httpmime` to version `4.3.4`, it's a fix version change, but still a misalignment (should be harmless though).

In this case it seems you are adding governance at parent level in `dependencyManagement` (good approach), but then at the level of one of the modules you need to override it. That can happen, but better to properly comment it, for maintenance and for the future yourself looking at it in the future.

Also note: other modules in this project would not be affected by this change, that is, they will still get version `4.5.2`. If the final result of the whole multimodule build is an `ear` or `war` file, for example, carefully check what you eventually get.

Comment: @MyTitle did this help out?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in a simple maven project to have 2 different versions of the same artifact in the classpath. So you cannot have 4.3.2 and 4.5.2 versions in the classpath simultaneously.

However there are several options... You can either

- use in your project the older version (4.3.*), compatible with sendgrid-java dependency (simplest way); or
- update sendgrid-java dependency, if newer one is compatible with http components 4.5.* (preferred way); or
- mark sendgrid-java as a 'provided' dependency, build a separate class loader in runtime and load it with correct dependencies versions (a bit tricky, but I saw this approach in a couple bank applications)